# MIDI controller problem

Tags: keyboard, music, midi

I bought the Arturia Keystep, and I looked up on the website. There was no linux version of the driver/midi center. Any help?

Comment: MIDI itself should work without a separate driver. The additional control software might run in WINE.

Comment: I used WINE to install the additional software "MIDI center". It doesn't seem to work, keeps crashing. Can you tell me some alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to see your MIDI controller when you run:

```
lsusb
```

then [this guide](http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html) should get you set up with the basics.  It goes into quite a lot of detail and discusses possible errors you might face and I wouldn't want to skip anything or take credit away from it.

This command should display your controller:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

You do **not** need WINE for any of this.

On Ubuntu 16.04, I then needed to do the following:

Add an audio group to run your software at the right priority:

```
sudo addgroup audio
```

Add yourself to the audio group:

```
sudo adduser $USER audio
```

Check what address your soundcard is on for output (it's usually hw:0):

```
aplay -l
```

Install Fluidsynth and a soundfont which will act as your synthesizer:

```
sudo apt-get install fluidsynth
sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm
```

Install JACK2 which will be the sound server that sits on top of Alsa:

```
sudo apt-get install jackd2
```

Run the JACK server, but allow it to bypass any concurrent pulseaudio process:

```
pasuspender -- jackd -d alsa --device hw:0 --rate 44100 --period 1024
```

Run the synthesizer with one of the default sounds:

```
fluidsynth --server --audio-driver=jack --connect-jack-outputs /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2
```

Now check what ports your servers are running on.  This should display your MIDI controller(note the number after client, I got `129`):

```
aconnect -i
```

And this should display the port for Fluidsynth(I got `128`):

```
aconnect -o
```

Connect the two(remember `129` and `128` are for illustrative purposes, use the port numbers you see in the above two commands):

```
aconnect 129:0 128:0
```

You should now be able to hear sounds when hitting the keys on your controller!