# Midi controller, soundcard problem

Tags: sound, midi

I'm following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864348/midi-controller-problem?newreg=ce4d0fb34649431f9f89ae92bb1dfbf3) on my Ubuntu 16.04 in order to connect a midi controller and be able to hear the sounds played without WINE or any special software with GUI.

Here are my outputs:

1) `lsusb` gives me

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 031: ID 13d3:3408 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 036: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 002 Device 035: ID 09e8:0045 AKAI  Professional M.I. Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The midi is AKAI Professional M.I. Corp. Good.

2) This command should display my controller:
`cat /proc/asound/cards`

Its output is

```
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                     HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7a1c000 irq 52
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7a18000 irq 51
2 [II             ]: USB-Audio - MPK Mini Mk II
                     AKAI MPK Mini Mk II at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed
```

How exactly should I interpret this?

3) Next I should run the following commands:

`sudo addgroup audio`

`sudo adduser $USER audio`  (replacing $USER accordingly)

`sudo apt-get install fluidsynth`

`sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm`

`sudo apt-get install jackd2`

4) Next I should check what address my soundcard is on for output with 
 `aplay -l`, whose output is below. How do I read it? In later steps, I need to connect the midi with the fluidsynth by knowing the soundcard address.

```
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3236 Analog [ALC3236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

5) Next I should run the JACK server, but allow it to bypass any concurrent pulseaudio process, but I inserted the wrong device address.

`pasuspender -- jackd -d alsa --device hw:0 --rate 44100 --period 1024`

I get:

```
jackdmp 1.9.11
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

Comment: `aplay` does not show MIDI devices; use `amidi -l` or `aplaymidi -l`. Jack does not start because you have told it to use `hw:0`, which does not exist. And you have not told us what your actual goal is.

Comment: I elaborated my goal and problem, thanks for pointing that out.